# Save GeoDataFrame to .jpg file

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas, jpg

I have a GeoPandas DataFrame (loaded from a shapefile) containing a number of polygons which looks like this:

```py
                                            geometry  raster_val
0  POLYGON ((8.56799 47.80800, 8.56799 47.77200, ...         1.0
1  POLYGON ((6.73199 47.12400, 6.73199 47.08800, ...         1.0
2  POLYGON ((10.36799 47.01600, 10.36799 46.98000...         1.0
3  POLYGON ((8.60399 46.51200, 8.60399 46.47600, ...         1.0
```

Is there any elegant way to print/plot those polygons into a `.jpg` file?

Comment: I have never used GeoPandas but looking at the [mapping documentation](http://geopandas.org/mapping.html) it seems that you just need to call `your_dataframe.plot()`. You can pass optional parameters for further customization and then simply call `plt.savefig()` to save the figure as a `.jpg` file. Let me know if the `plot()` method works so I can expand this comment as an answer.

Comment: @MarceloVilla
That way works and would be my suggested answer. I have nothing to add so I leave it for you to answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taking a look at the [geopandas mapping documentation](http://geopandas.org/mapping.html), it seems that you can plot a `GeoDataFrame` by calling the `plot()` method on it. Here is one example from the documentation:

```py
import geopandas
world = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
world.plot()
```

[image]

To export the plot as a `.jpg` file, you can simply use the [`matplotlib.pyplot.savefig()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html) function. The code would be similar to:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.savefig('world.jpg')
```

You can, of course, modify the plot by passing several arguments to the `plot()` method.

Comment: That's great! Thanks! But what if I already have a figure which I'm displaying (like `plt.imshow(ndvi_layer, cmap='RdYlGn')`) and I want to draw those polygons on top of that?

Comment: @ksnn As it is a rather different question than the original one you posted, I'd suggest creating a new question and linking it here so I can answer it.

Comment: Sure! I just posted it here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/344076/plotting-goedataframe-on-raster