# Plotting GoeDataFrame on a raster

Tags: python, raster, geopandas, visualisation, rasterio

I have a bunch of polygons which I loaded from a shapefile into a `fields` GeoDataFrame:

```py
   geometry                                           raster_val
0  POLYGON ((8.56799 47.80800, 8.56799 47.77200, ...         1.0
1  POLYGON ((6.73199 47.12400, 6.73199 47.08800, ...         1.0
```

I plot them using:

```py
fields.plot(color='white', edgecolor='black')
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

I also have a raster layer (`ndvi_layer`) which is basically a numpy array which I plot using:

```py
fig, ax = matplotlib.pyplot.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
rasterio.plot.show(ndvi_layer, ax=ax, cmap='RdYlGn')
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

Is there any way to plot the polygons on top of the raster? What if the polygons don't have the same CRS as the raster?

Comment: I think, this solve your requirements. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/294072/how-can-i-superimpose-a-geopandas-dataframe-on-a-raster-plot

Comment: You're right! Initially, it didn't work because of the difference in CRS of raster and polygons. Once I adjusted CRS of the GeoDataFrame using `.to_crs()` it all works now!