# Software used to plot GPS data on a map to be saved as an image

Tags: software-recommendations, rendering, gpx, free-software

I have GPS data from some bike rides which I'd like to use to create a video overlay showing my position on a map at a given point in time. The plan is to find some library for Python or JavaScript which can render a map to be saved as an image and then use FFMPEG to create a video using each image as a frame.

I see [Folium](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/) and [Leaflet.js](https://leafletjs.com/) mentioned elsewhere, but Leaflet seems to require a browser for rendering and Folium is in turn built using Leaflet and uses Selenium to instrument a browser to render with Leaflet.

I've been able to do something similar with [CARTOframes](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartoframes), though I haven't investigated fully enough to tell if it will suit this use case.

Are there any other good libraries to be aware of that can render GPS data to a map without requiring a browser?

Comment: For software recommendations there is the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: What about geopandas https://geopandas.org/en/stable/gallery/index.html  and matplotlib?  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/343313/save-geodataframe-to-jpg-file

Answer (score -1):

Unless you want complete automation, this might do the trick

https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/animating_time_series.html

[Download QGIS](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html)